# In R what makes NULL atomical and therefore unable to exist in a vector?

Tags: r

In R for Everyone by Jared P. Lander on p. 54 it says "...NULL is atomical and cannot exist within a vector. If used inside a vector, it simply disappears."

I understand the concept of being atomic is being indivisible and that NULL represents "nothingness", used commonly to handle returns that are undefined.

Therefore, is NULL atomical b/c it has this one value always of "nothingness", meaning something simply does not exist and therefore R's way of handling that is to just not let it exist in a vector or on assignment in a list it will actually remove that element?

Trying to wrap my head around it and find a more intuitive and comprehensive answer.

Comment: I'd appreciate if you'd reconsider the issue, now that we have modified R, such that in the future  `is.atomic(NULL)`  will no longer be true.  Rather it will be true only and exactly for atomic vector arguments.  (Yes, I'm the MM from the R core team).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my opinion talking about vectors as being "atomic" is more confusing than helpful. Instead, consider that R has a series of data types built into the language. They are given by definition and are distinct from one another.

For example, one such data type is "integer vector", which represents a sequence of integer values. Note that R does not have a data type of "integer". If we are talking about integer 5 in R, it is actually an integer vector of length 1.

Another built-in data type is NULL. There is a single object of type NULL, which is also called NULL. Since NULL is a type and an object, but not an integer value, it cannot be part of an integer vector.

Missing data in an integer vector are represented by NA. In this context NA is considered an integer value. Note that NA can also be a numeric value, logical value, etc. NA is a not a data type, but a value.

A complete list of built-in data types can be found in the R source code and also in the documentation, e.g. https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-ints.html#SEXPTYPEs

Comment: R for Everyone does a good job of explaining most of your answer, like using NA, NULL being an object and a value, etc. However, for me at least - it wasn't intuitive to logically deduce that since there aren't no vectors of data type NULL and they don't hold objects, it would never have a NULL value. Thanks for the great explanation!

Comment: Thanks for the kind words. I am not familiar with the book you mention, but I do want to pick on the statement "If used inside a vector, it simply disappears." It does not make sense. It is like saying that you cannot stick an orange into an apple. You should not even try comparing apples and oranges. For example, if "a" is a vector of length 3 and you attempt a[2] = NULL, you will get an error. You just tried to stick an orange into an apple. Now, someone would say, "hold on, you can write c(1, 2, NULL, 4) and you get back the integer vector '1 2 4'." (to be continued)

Comment: No, you did not just stick a NULL into a vector. You tried to concatenate 3 integer vectors of length 1 with a NULL object. Before doing the concatenation, the "c" function will convert all 4 objects into a common data type, picking the type in such a way to not loose any information. In this case the NULL will be converted to an integer vector. So the concatenation will actually be c(1, 2, as.integer(NULL), 4). If you look at the result of as.integer(NULL), the outcome of the original concatenation will become obvious.

Comment: The outcome (I had to try you teased) was integer(0) - meaning an empty integer vector. Makes sense, great deep dive!

Answer (score 5):

Let me come back to this "old" Q.  I'm a (founding) R-core member and for us
"atomic vector" is an important concept we've used in many places in both documentation and also the source code of R itself, both on the R and C level.

Your Q is very good:  *Currently*, it is the case that  `is.atomic(NULL)`
returns `TRUE` in R, but we have several times discussed that this may be intuitive to some ({"`NULL` being the smallest object in R at all, you should treat it as an atom"}),
but is really in contradiction to how we have defined "atomic vector"s in many places, and also how the C-level internal `isVectorAtomic()` is defined and used: an atomic vector in that sense must be of one of the 6 atomic vector types:  { logical, integer, double, complex, character, raw }.

Currently I am working towards *changing* `is.atomic()`  with the plan that a future release of R  will have   `is.atomic(NULL)` to become `FALSE`.
This is not a promise, but the declaration of an intent.

Comment: Note that for about 10 days, in the *development* version of R, "R-devel", `is.atomic(NULL)`  is no longer true, but "truly" `FALSE`.    So this inconsistency will be gone soonish. The current R-devel is meant to become R (version 4.4.0 probably) around April 2024: https://developer.r-project.org/blosxom.cgi/R-devel/NEWS/2023/09/29#n2023-09-29

Comment: Thanks for following up on this, very insightful and gives context to what's to come!