# Why is $ a valid operator on NULL?

Tags: r, data-structures

In R, the extraction operator `$` is valid on recursive-like objects *and* `NULL`, but errors otherwise.

```r
c(1:3)$a
# Error in c(1:3)$a : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

But is there any intuition or reason why it works on `NULL`?

```r
NULL$a
# NULL
```

Also odd is that if you bind `NULL` to a name first, it will coerce it into a list:

```
x <- NULL
x$a <- 1
# $a
# [1] 1
```

Perhaps this makes some sense if you are working with a list and there is risk of some operation returning `NULL`, but the same could be said for atomic vectors. Or since `NULL` can be coerced to the type on the RHS and the most fundamental objects to use `$` are lists?

Comment: I think in the early days, `NULL` and `list()` were the same thing.  Nowadays they are similar, but not the same.  Obviously `is.null(list())` returns `FALSE`, but also `NULL` is a special singleton object, and you can't set attributes on it.  I'd guess the `NULL$a` and `NULL[1]` behaviour is a leftover from the old days.

Comment: Adding to the confusion: ```x <- NULL; is.atomic(x) #TRUE; is.vector(x) #FALSE```

Comment: @user2554330 Why do you think this? It might be implemented like that in Scheme but do you have a reference that it was ever like that in R (or S)?

Comment: Subset assignment to `NULL` is clearly documented in `help("[")`. Asking for reasoning of design decisions by language developers seems off-topic to me.

Comment: @M-- Why is that confusing? `NULL` is clearly atomic but mode "NULL" is not among the modes listed in `is.vector` (and it makes sense to me, `NULL` is fundamentally not a vector object).

Comment: @Roland well, it is confusing to me, and seems I am not alone. This will(had) change(d)  :/ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59558295/in-r-what-makes-null-atomical-and-therefore-unable-to-exist-in-a-vector#comment136241005_59558295 (but don't take what I say right now too seriously as I've been on my phone for a couple of hours using an online compiler, while pretending that I am trying to go to sleep)

Comment: @Roland:  If you look at the NEWS for R 1.1.0, you'll see this:  "ave(1:3) now works (as when is.null(list()) was TRUE years ago)."  I don't have anything more definite than that, I was relying on old memories.  I've been using R for a long time.

Comment: OK, reading up on `help("[")` as @Roland said, this is a documented behavior. Not much beyond that: *"When `$<-` is applied to a NULL `x`, it first coerces `x` to `list()`. This is what also happens with `[[<-` where in R versions less than 4.y.z, a length one value resulted in a length one (atomic) vector."*

Answer (score 1):

`NULL` is conceptually an empty pairlist, as mentioned in `help("NULL")`,

> `NULL` is also used as the empty pairlist: see the examples.  Because pairlists are often promoted to lists, you may encounter `NULL` being promoted to an empty list.

and again in `help("pairlist")`,

> An empty pairlist, `pairlist()` is the same as `NULL`.  This is different from `list()`: some but not all operations will promote an empty pairlist to an empty list.

so the validity of subscripts of `NULL` and subassignment to `NULL` is implicitly inherited from the validity of those operations on pairlists.  However, behaviour is not always inherited.  In R 4.3.2, I observe:

```
              call  x = NULL                  x = <nonempty pairlist>
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
1   is.pairlist(x)  TRUE                      TRUE
2       is.list(x)  FALSE                     TRUE
3  is.recursive(x)  FALSE                     TRUE
4             x[i]  always NULL               coerces to type "list"
5           x[[i]]  always NULL               extracts directly                                               
6           x$name  always NULL               extracts directly
7    x[i] <- value  coerces to typeof(value)  coerces to type "list"
                    if length(value) > 0
8  x[[i]] <- value  coerces to type "list"    preserves type "pairlist"
9  x$name <- value  coerces to type "list"    preserves type "pairlist"
```

where I would say that cases 5 and 6 are clearly "consistent" and cases 4, 7, 8, and 9 are clearly "inconsistent".  But the differences are all documented, so ...